# Not able to create process builder/flow on Program Rebate Type Benefit object in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

When i'm trying to create a process builder or Flow on 'Program Rebate Type Benefit' object, i'm getting below error.

We can't reference "ProgramRebateTypeBenefit" fields. Check that they're still valid references and that you have permission to access them. For help, contact Salesforce Customer Support. Error ID: -191673043

Please guide me here.
I'm totally stucked on this.

Thanking you in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

I know you posted this months ago but for the sake of posterity I wanted to point out that there is a known issue out there for this problem: https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000j5k8EAAQ/error-on-opening-update-records-element-which-is-configured-on-custom-object-with-lookup-relationship-to-standard-object

> Note: Though the error is popping up, the flow will run as expected. To make any changes to the Update record component, you can delete and re-create the component.